# webpack dev server + react hot loading = many strange requests to some mysterious /app/info

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader

I've started to use webpack not so long ago. Everything's perfect and React hot loading works great. But there's one this with webpack dev server that I cannot understand. When I use my webapp issues endless requests to /app/info. And it gets back 404.

What is this? How can I turn it off?

Here's the log in console:

[image]

And here's my config (it's pretty much generic config for the React hot loading):

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {

  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client',
    'bootstrap-loader',
    './src/app.js',
  ],

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'resources', 'static', 'app'),
    filename: 'app.js',
    publicPath: '/app',
  },

  devServer: {
    headers:
    {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:10000',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
    },
  },

  // devtool: '#source-map',

  resolve: { extensions: ['', '.js'] },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015,' +
                                'presets[]=react,' +
                                'presets[]=stage-0,' +
                                'plugins[]=' + path.join(__dirname, 'babelRelayPlugin') + ',' +
                                'plugins[]=transform-runtime,' +
                                'plugins[]=transform-object-rest-spread'],
      },

      { test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'postcss'] },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'postcss', 'sass'] },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?|png|jpg)$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=25000',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
        loader: 'file',
      },

      // Use one of these to serve jQuery for Bootstrap scripts:

      // Bootstrap 4
      { test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' },

      // Bootstrap 3
      { test: /bootstrap-sass\/assets\/javascripts\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' },
    ],
  },

  postcss: [autoprefixer],

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comment fixed my issue https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/326#issuecomment-171344167. I changed `'webpack-dev-server/client',` to `'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/',`